# How to give GitHub a url with a port number when creating a webhook

Tags: github, github-api

I want to use GitHub webhooks, but GitHub is stripping away the port number from the urls I give it, so they don't work. This seems like a new thing because it used to work. Is there any way to tell GitHub to keep the port numbers in there?

Note: I'm creating the webhooks via the API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that port number is stripped away.

```
POST https://api.github.com/repos/my-name/my-repo/hooks
```

with body:

```
{
  "name": "web",
  "active": true,
  "events": [
    "push",
    "pull_request"
  ],
  "config": {
    "url": "http://example.com:345/webhook",
    "content_type": "json"
  }
}
```

Creates the WebHook:

[image]

BTW, on this page GitHub renders url without the port number.

But if you click "Edit" button:

[image]

The port number is presented.

The same you'll get if you execute

```
GET https://api.github.com/repos/my-name/my-repo/hooks



  {
    "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/my-name/my-repo/hooks/7221574",
    "test_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/my-name/my-repo/hooks/7221574/test",
    "ping_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/my-name/my-repo/hooks/7221574/pings",
    "id": 7221574,
    "name": "web",
    "active": true,
    "events": [
      "push",
     "pull_request"
    ],
    "config": {
    "url": "http://example.com:345/webhook",
    "content_type": "json"
    },
    "last_response": {
    "code": 504,
    "status": "timeout",
    "message": "Service Timeout",
    },
    "updated_at": "2016-02-08T09:37:45Z",
    "created_at": "2016-02-08T09:37:45Z"
    }
}
```

Make sure that:

1. You post valid url
2. Body is valid json
3. You have rights to create webhook
4. You can create it with simple client (Postman, Advanced REST client)
5. Your GitHub client library doesn't remove port number

Comment: @Shawn Same here. I use github to inform my git on PLESK to retrieve the latest code. If i post from Postman to the exact same address also with the port number, it works. Response:

    HTTP/1.1 204 No Content
    Server: sw-cp-server
    Date: Mon, 11 Oct 2021 22:10:26 GMT
    Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
    Connection: keep-alive

My server pulls the latest code. So that code pull really works. Any clue anyone why the github.com cannot inform my server and Postman can? The github webhooks report: We couldn’t deliver this payload: failed to connect to host